# New Project on Android Studio with Login Activity throws error

Tags: java, android, kotlin

My goal is to make a simple app with Android Native. However, the Android Studio throws error `Inheritance from an interface with '@JvmDefault' members is only allowed with -Xjvm-default option` on file `app/java/com.x.x/ui/login/LoginViewModelFactory` on line 12. This happens when I tried to run the app to the virtual device.

The culprit is the `ViewModelProvider.Factory` from the `androidx.lifeccle.ViewModelProvider`. I tried to see the code with `right-click + Go To + Declaration or Usages`. However, the I don't see the `@JvmDefaults` on top of the interface Factory declaration.

What I've did:

1. I installed Android Studio on Mac Mini M1, I believe a month ago.
2. I installed Java JDK 8 and 17. The Android Studio terminal return version 8.

   ```
   openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_292-b10)
   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
   ```
3. Create New Project, I selected Kotlin and Login Activity on the menu.

LoginViewModelFactory

```
package com.x.x.ui.login

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.x.x.data.LoginDataSource
import com.x.x.data.LoginRepository

/**
 * ViewModel provider factory to instantiate LoginViewModel.
 * Required given LoginViewModel has a non-empty constructor
 */
class LoginViewModelFactory : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
```

Comment: You may check my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73252882/why-am-i-getting-an-inheritance-from-an-interface-with-jvmdefault-members-is/73253555#73253555

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try putting these line inside of android{} block in module build.gradle file

   ```
    kotlinOptions{
        freeCompilerArgs += [
           "-Xjvm-default=all",
        ]
   }
   ```

Comment: It works, would you care explain what does `-Xjvm-default=all` does?